# Search files with UNICODE names

Tags: c++, file, search, unicode, wstring

I have tried to compile this program after the compilation success it print on the console windows the current directory of the program.
But the job of the program is to show me all the files with .doc extension, also it works fine when i don't use the wide string `wstring()`  .So this is the problem i want to compile this program with wstring functionality .

**UPDATE:**

**THIS CODE WORK PROPERLY:**

```
#define UNICODE
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
/*
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

typedef std::string UTF8String;
*/
int SearchDirectory(std::vector<std::string> &refvecFiles,
                    const std::string         &refcstrRootDirectory,
                    const std::string         &refcstrExtension,
                    bool                     bSearchSubdirectories = true)
{
  std::string      strFilePath;             // Filepath
  std::string      strPattern;              // Pattern
  std::string      strExtension;            // Extension
  HANDLE          hFile;                   // Handle to file
  WIN32_FIND_DATA FileInformation;         // File information


  strPattern = refcstrRootDirectory + "\\*.*";

  hFile = ::FindFirstFile(strPattern.c_str(), &FileInformation);
  if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    do
    {
      if(FileInformation.cFileName[0] != '.')
      {
        strFilePath.erase();
        strFilePath = refcstrRootDirectory + "\\" + FileInformation.cFileName;

        if(FileInformation.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
          if(bSearchSubdirectories)
          {
            // Search subdirectory
            int iRC = SearchDirectory(refvecFiles,
                                      strFilePath,
                                      refcstrExtension,
                                      bSearchSubdirectories);
            if(iRC)
              return iRC;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          // Check extension
          strExtension = FileInformation.cFileName;
          strExtension = strExtension.substr(strExtension.rfind(".") + 1);

          if(strExtension == refcstrExtension)
          {
            // Save filename
            refvecFiles.push_back(strFilePath);
          }
        }
      }
    } while(::FindNextFile(hFile, &FileInformation) == TRUE);

    // Close handle
    ::FindClose(hFile);

    DWORD dwError = ::GetLastError();
    if(dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
      return dwError;
  }

  return 0;
}


// Prototype for conversion functions
std::wstring StringToWString(const std::string& s);
std::string WStringToString(const std::wstring& s);

std::wstring StringToWString(const std::string& s)
{
    std::wstring temp(s.length(),L' ');
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), temp.begin());
    return temp;
}


std::string WStringToString(const std::wstring& s)
{
    std::string temp(s.length(), ' ');
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), temp.begin());
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
  int                      iRC         = 0;
  std::vector<std::string > vecAviFiles;
  std::vector<std::string > vecTxtFiles;


  // Search 'c:' for '.avi' files including subdirectories
  iRC = SearchDirectory(vecAviFiles, "c:", "doc");
  if(iRC)
  {
    std::cout << "Error " << iRC << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }


// Print results
  for(std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iterAvi = vecAviFiles.begin(); iterAvi != vecAviFiles.end(); ++iterAvi)
    std::wcout << *iterAvi << std::endl;

}
```

---

**NOT WORKING CODE:**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int SearchDirectory(std::vector<std::wstring> &refvecFiles,
                    const std::wstring        &refcstrRootDirectory,
                    const std::wstring        &refcstrExtension,
                    bool                     bSearchSubdirectories = true)
{
  std::wstring     strFilePath;             // Filepath
  std::wstring     strPattern;              // Pattern
  std::wstring     strExtension;            // Extension
  HANDLE          hFile;                   // Handle to file
  WIN32_FIND_DATAW FileInformation;         // File information

  strPattern = refcstrRootDirectory + L"\\*.*";

  hFile = ::FindFirstFileW(strPattern.c_str(), &FileInformation);
  if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    do
    {
      if(FileInformation.cFileName[0] != '.')
      {
        strFilePath.erase();
        strFilePath = refcstrRootDirectory + L"\\" + FileInformation.cFileName;

        if(FileInformation.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
          if(bSearchSubdirectories)
          {
            // Search subdirectory
            int iRC = SearchDirectory(refvecFiles,
                                      strFilePath,
                                      refcstrExtension,
                                      bSearchSubdirectories);
            if(iRC)
              return iRC;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          // Check extension
          strExtension = FileInformation.cFileName;
          strExtension = strExtension.substr(strExtension.rfind(L".") + 1);

          if(strExtension == refcstrExtension)
          {
            // Save filename
            refvecFiles.push_back(strFilePath);
          }
        }
      }
    } while(::FindNextFileW(hFile, &FileInformation) == TRUE);

    // Close handle
    ::FindClose(hFile);

    DWORD dwError = ::GetLastError();
    if(dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
      return dwError;
  }

  return 0;
}


int main()
{
  int                      iRC         = 0;
  std::vector<std::wstring> vecAviFiles;

  // Search 'c:' for '.avi' files including subdirectories
  iRC = SearchDirectory(vecAviFiles, L"c:", L"doc");
  if(iRC)
  {
    std::cout << "Error " << iRC << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  // Print results
  for(std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iterAvi = vecAviFiles.begin(); iterAvi != vecAviFiles.end(); ++iterAvi)
    std::wcout << *iterAvi << std::endl;
}
```

What I want to know is why the second program won't work?

Comment: So what's the error you're getting?

Comment: firstly:
X:\C++\boost iterator\bin\Debug\
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 12.165 s
Press any key to continue.
also this is not the current directory of the process
secondly:
i will change the .doc to another extension and this not the problem
the problem is that i can't get the path of the files with .doc (or wathever) extension.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. My only suggestion is to use case insensitive string comparison here: strExtension == refcstrExtension

Comment: also what do you get on the console screen
for me it show me only the directory where is the first .doc file

Answer (score 0):

You're Doing It Wrong™.

Consider `strPattern = refcstrRootDirectory + L"\\*.*";`. That `*.*` is there for a reason. It's where you specify the file pattern that you're looking for. If you want to look for `*.doc` files, say so: `strPattern = refcstrRootDirectory + L"\\*." + refcstrExtension;`

Also, some style notes:

- Drop the type prefixes. That's a convention used in weakly typed languages; C++ is strongly typed.
- Define variables where you need them, not earlier:

  - `std::wstring Pattern = RootDirectory + L"\\*.*";`
  - `HFILE File = ::FindFirstFileW(Pattern.c_str(), &FileInformation);`
- There's no need to erase a string if you're assigning a new value. E.g. this works fine.

  - `FilePath = RootDirectory + L"\\" + FileInformation.cFileName;`
- Check what this does to files without extensions.
- You're leaking a file handle in `if(iRC) return iRC;`. (C++ objects are cleaned automatically, but this is a C API).